# how to parse subscript or superscript within glue()

Tags: r

I try to create a text label with sub/superscript for R basic `text()` using `glue()`. Is it possible to do that?

```
x <- rnorm(10)
plot(x)
text(x = max(x)-0.5, pos = 4,
     labels = glue("Some text {expression(R^2)} and some text
                   next line {expression(R[0])}"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using Unicode of course

```
text(x = max(x)-0.5, pos = 4,
     labels = glue("Some text R\U2070 and some text
                   next line R\U2092"))
```

[image]